# Editing a USB scanners driver file

Tags: windows, usb, driver, barcode-scanner

tldr below

Hi I've been having a problem with a POS system where every second product or so scanned comes up with the "enter a new product window", I have noticed this happens because after scanning the barcode the scanner hits "return" sometimes before the POS system can load the product, if the product hasn't loaded hitting "return" sends you to the "enter a new product window"

tldr

If I could edit the driver files and add a couple seconds delay before hitting "return" it would fix my problem, Im an amateur programmer at best but I just wanted to know if its possible. Im running windows 7 and my Scanner is a "Esky USB Laser Scan Handheld Barcode Reader" It uses drivers: kbdclass.sys kbdhid.sys SynTP.sys

I tried to be as descriptive as possible, if any more information is needed please let me know and thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to respond:)

Comment: Thanks:) Saved me a few hours of banging my head against a brick wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kbdclass.sys and kbdhid.sys are microsoft drivers used for keyboards. You can't change them. Even if you could, this would change the behaviour of your keyboard as well, which is probably not something that is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner not always hits return.
It may depends on driver setup or something. 
Google "barcode scanner postfix"